# Rank Function Acsending Order but make 0 the bottom

Tags: excel-2007

I am using the ranking function =RANK(W8,$W$8:$W$26,1), however, I want to ensure that any score with a 0 always falls to the bottom, 1 being the best and so on.

I did try adding in an IF statement but this didn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant:

```
=IF(W8=0,COUNT($W$8:$W$26),RANK(W8,$W$8:$W$26,1))
```